Matching lhs2tex sytle with verbatim style
I would like to match the font of the verbatim environment with the code blocks produced using lhs2TeX, while still keeping the nice lhs2TeX features like tabular alignment with polycode.fmt and bold highlighting of keywords.
I thought I could just redefine \hscodestyle to use \ttfamily. However, changing \hscodestyle doesn't seem to do anything at all.
I am using XeLaTeX if that matters.
\documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart}

\usepackage{listings}

% Work around acmart and lhs2tex incompatibility
\let\Bbbk\undefined

%include polycode.fmt

\renewcommand{\hscodestyle}{\ttfamily}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
-- verbatim
type Matrix n m = Compose (Vec n) (Vec m)
\end{verbatim}

> -- lhs2tex
> type Matrix n m = Compose (Vec n) (Vec m)

\end{document}


If for some reason this is not possible, I would at the very least need to make the output of lhs2TeX nicer, fixing e.g. the kerning between ( and Vec in this example...

By looking at the generated .tex and then randomly grepping for where some fragments might be coming from, I found that \hscodestyle is a red herring for font style, because the various %subst directives will override it on a token by token basis.
So instead the solution to this is to change the %subst directives themselves:
\documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart}

\usepackage{listings}

% Work around acmart and lhs2tex incompatibility
\let\Bbbk\undefined

%include polycode.fmt

%subst keyword a = "\texttt{\textbf{" a "}}"
%subst conid a = "\texttt{" a "}"
%subst varid a = "\texttt{" a "}"

\begin{document}

This is verbatim:

\begin{verbatim}
type Matrix n m = Compose (Vec n) (Vec m)
\end{verbatim}

And this is Literate Haskell:

> type Matrix n m = Compose (Vec n) (Vec m)

\end{document}


